# Rendering Foreign Key Elements from Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the standard django polls models

```
class Poll(models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):

    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, null=True, blank=True)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vote_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

In the serialisers I have added a reference to foreign key as follows :

```
class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = ('id', 'question_text', 'pub_date', 'choices')
```

I have created the choices specific to the questions by the django admin. In the poll list from django rest framework, I expect to see the list of choices associated with the poll. It only shows the Poll objects as follows.

[image]

Can someone guide me, as to what has gone missing, and how can I see the choices associated with the Poll?

Comment: You can add a `related_name` in your model's foreign key field then in DRF just add  `source=related_name_used` otherwise, use `choice_set` as a default reverse name for your model's foreign key field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since reverse manager for choice objects is `choice_set` You should set [`source='choice_set'`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) for `choices` field:

```
class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False, source='choice_set')
```

Comment: thank you for providing the quick answer. if I want the votes to be casted, how would you approach that? would you go by making read_only as false or would you create a new model say `Vote`  and then have `questions` and `choices` built inside them, and then open up a post request via another URL?

Comment: @ElonMusk I suppose second option is better. You may need Vote model to track vote history later.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [@neverwalkaloner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641249/neverwalkaloner)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51323035/8283848), you could do it this way also,

```
class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices_set = ChoiceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = ('id', 'question_text', 'pub_date', 'choices_set')
```

Comment: thank you, for the quick answer, very helpful indeed. 

I guess, if I want the choice to be altered, i can make read_only = False,  is that right?

Comment: By default, `read_only=False`, and `read_only` meant for altering the **values**. But, In your case, It's not logical from `/polls/` API